# Connecting to my bigquery datasets using jupyter notebook on GCP ( VM )

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I try to visualize my bigquery data in a jupyter notebook, I follow the steps described in the following link :https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter

the problem is that when I execute the command:
 
`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]`
the result is the following :

[image]

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa83e0f2ba8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/google-cloud-bigquery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa83e0f2d68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/google-cloud-bigquery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa83e0f21d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/google-cloud-bigquery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa83e0f2f28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/google-cloud-bigquery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa83e0f2e80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/google-cloud-bigquery/<br/>
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google.cloud.bigquery (from versions: none)<br/>
ERROR: No matching distribution found for google.cloud.bigquery
```

Comment: I believe your error is due to the fact that you forgot to install some necessary python dependency. In the terminal, just use `sudo apt-get install python3.6` , `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt install python3-pip`. After running these commands, I was able to run the command you mentioned using pip3.  In addition, I was able to execute the full tutorial using the Jupyter Notebook in the AI Platform. After creating a new instance and opening the Notebook just use: `!pip3 install pip update`, `!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]`. Did it work for you?

Comment: nope, it doesn't work, the same error

Comment: I have followed the tutorial and It worked for me. Since you are executing this command in a VM, I would now suggest you to create a virtual environment to execute the code. In your VM execute the commands: `pip install virtualenv` , 
    `virtualenv <your-env>` , 
    `source <your-env>/bin/activate`
    `<your-env>/bin/pip install google-cloud-bigquery `. Also, you can have a look in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup) how to set a virtual environment.